# How to compare " only dates ; not time " using datepicker JQuery?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How to compare dates only using following snippet

```
 var selectedDate =  $("input[id='accountDate']").datepicker('getDate');

        if (selectedDate != null) {
            var now = new Date();
            console.log("selectedDate:" + selectedDate + " | now: " + now)

            if (selectedDate < now) {
                do this and this and this
                }
            }
        }
```

Log Output:

```
selectedDate (Entered Date):Tue Sep 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Standard Time) 
| now: Tue Sep 01 2015 09:43:33 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Standard Time)
```

As you can see in output dates are same still it is executing (selectedDate < now); which it should not. I think it is due to time issue.

How can we compare dates (not time)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the time part of now to blank like

```
var selectedDate = $("input[id='accountDate']").datepicker('getDate');

if (selectedDate != null) {
    var now = new Date();
    now.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
    console.log("selectedDate:" + selectedDate + " | now: " + now)

    if (selectedDate < now) {
        do this and this and this
    }
}
```